# Mouse Pointer FPS is very low

Tags: mouse, windows-11, mouse-cursor, windows-11-v22h2

I'm having a mouse pointer issue Windows 11.

The issue is that the pointer displayed on the screen is not refreshed very often. It makes the pointer feel sluggish. I'm *not* referring to mouse pointer speed. I have tried uninstalling the mouse driver in "Device Manager" and then plugging in a different mouse. I've messed around with various settings. It's not mouse trails. It's not pointer shadow. I can't find any 3rd party mouse driver/utility running, esp. not in the system tray. Booting into Safe Mode made no difference.

When I move the mouse back and forth (left and right) quickly, at about 8 swipes per second (4 round trips per second), I get different results on one computer vs another. On the "good/responsive" Windows machine (and Ubuntu), I see several mouse pointers between each side (in the middle of the swipes). On the "bad/sluggish" computer, I typically only see the pointer at each edge. So clearly the frame rate is lower. (Pointer trails is turned off on all computers tested).

And this is all when I'm not playing a game. When I'm playing a game, the overall FPS is fine. (I have a GTX 1070Ti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue in my case was the monitor refresh rate. The refresh rate was originally 60 Hz when I got the computer. However, recently, I made some changes which resulted in using 30 Hz.

Apparently, for the games I had been playing, going from 60 Hz to 30 Hz was not as noticeable. However, when using the mouse pointer in Windows (not in a game), the issue became incredibly noticeable and painful to use.

I found this out by reading the monitor's manual. The manual made it clear that 60 Hz was supported only when using DisplayPort -- when using HDMI, it would revert to 30 Hz. I checked the Windows 11 display settings and confirmed that this was accurate. The fix was to revert to using the monitor's DisplayPort input, and ensuring that Windows 11 was configured to use the monitor at 60 Hz.

Next time, I'm buying a gaming monitor which supports a higher Hz value. :)

Comment: That's probably a combination of a high-resolution monitor that was new-enough when released that the HDMI version with enough bandwidth to support that resolution at full refresh either didn't exist or was too expensive to implement for it's market segment.  It's likely games aren't running at 4k and so can use faster rates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the mouse polling rate? Sometimes you can change it by downloading the software provided by the manufacturer of your mouse. From experience it can sometimes get sluggish when the rate is too high, when using a gaming mouse for example. I have mice that have an extra button on them to change the polling rate without extra software too. I'm not sure if it'll fix the issue but it's worth giving a try.

Comment: It is a "gaming" mouse. I'm not sure how I'd change the polling rate, but you might be onto something.